# Reactjs e Redux state nao altera

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Boa tarde pessoal sou iniciante e estou tendo um problema na hora de atualizar meu state poderiam me ajudar ou dar alguma dica de como posso resolver isso

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Form, Button,Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


function getUsuario(usuario,action){
  return {
    type:'PEGAR_USUARIO',
    usuario:action.usuario,
  }
}

const FormLogin = ({usuario,dispatch}) => (

  <Container>
   <Form>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
      <Form.Label>Usuario</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Usuario"  onChange={(e)=>{ e.target.value}} />
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
      <Form.Label>Senha</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
    </Form.Group>
<Link to="/home" onClick={()=> {dispatch(getUsuario(usuario))}}>
    <Button variant="primary" type="submit"  >
      Entrar
    </Button>
    </Link >
  </Form >
  </Container>
)

export default connect(state => ({usuario: state.usuario}))(FormLogin);
```

store.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'


const INITIAL_STATE =
{
    usuario: ''
}
function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE , action){
    console.log(action)
    if(action.type === 'PEGAR_USUARIO'){
        return {...state, usuario:action.usuario}
    }
    return state;
}
const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

Comment: Mas qual o erro especificamente? Se você der um log no reducer, não chega lá?

Comment: O que preciso é que o valor do input seja armazenado na minha state porem ele nao armazena o valor da state nunca muda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu converti para um modelo em react-hooks que é muito mais fácil de entender do que no modelo "arcaico".

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Container, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

const App = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    })
    const { usuario } = useSelector(store => store) // destructure, isso é = const usuario = useSelector(store => store.usuario), é usado para não repetir a mesma propriedade
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(usuario)
    }, [usuario]) // quando atualizar a variável usuario ele vai logar isso
    return (
        <Container>
        <Form>
         <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
             <Form.Label>Usuario</Form.Label>
             <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Usuario" onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, username: e.target.value })} />
         </Form.Group>

         <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
             <Form.Label>Senha</Form.Label>
             <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
         </Form.Group>
         <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
         </Form.Group>
         <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'PEGAR_USUARIO', usuario: user })}>
             Entrar
         </Button>
     </Form >
     </Container>
    )
}

export default App
```

[image: Aqui como ficou o resultado (eu coloquei o redux-logger para garantir, mas era desnecessário por causa do useEffect)]
Eu supus que você usaria o estado `usuario` para guardar tanto o username quanto a senha. Desculpe se entendi errado. Caso tenha dúvidas pode perguntar.

[React Hooks Link](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)